# Windows resumed from sleep normaly after BSOD

Tags: windows-7, bsod, sleep, hybrid-sleep

I resumed windows from hybrid-sleep and it worked for a few seconds then crashed so I turned it off and turned it on about 2 hours later but instead of 'starting windows' as expected, it resumed normally as if the BSOD didn't happen.
Where else should I look for a crash report about this?

Also, while looking for similar questions I found this program 'BSOD Viewer' but it didn't find anything in 'C:\windows\Minidump'

This is the event viewer entry of the last successful resume

```
    The system has resumed from sleep.

    Sleep Time: ‎2015‎-‎06‎-‎11T00:30:49.445102400Z
    Wake Time: ‎2015‎-‎06‎-‎11T06:59:52.848019900Z

    Wake Source: Timer - FreeAlarmClock.exe
```

This is when the BSOD happened

```
    The system has resumed from sleep.

    Sleep Time: ‎2015‎-‎06‎-‎11T07:11:28.531810700Z
    Wake Time: ‎2015‎-‎06‎-‎11T08:43:34.632121900Z

    Wake Source: Unknown (That was 'Wake On LAN' app on my phone)
```

Comment: You are looking in the only location it the mini dump should be, if its not there, then it wasn't generated.

Comment: I guess Event Viewer MAY show something